# Resta de un vector e invertirlo con recursividad (recursion )en java

Tags: java, array, recursión

Muy buen día tengan, ¿podrían ayudarme por favor? Necesito hacer una resta de un vector (el cual tiene los valores {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}) con recursividad, ya realicé el programa, pero al correrlo me da como resultado 5, en vez de -35. ¿Pueden orientarme por favor?
El código que he hecho es el siguiente:

```
    package restavector;


public class RestaVector {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int resultado;
        int[]vector = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        resultado = RestaVector(vector, vector.length);
        System.out.println("La resta del valor es: "+resultado);
    } 
        
    public static int RestaVector(int[] vector, int tam) {
        if(tam==1)
            return vector[0];
        else
            return vector[tam - 1] - RestaVector(vector, tam - 1);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Hola, A qué te refieres con: ``A partir de un código me piden que reste un determinado vector``, ¿Cuál es el valor que esperabas?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: El vector tiene los siguientes valores: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, lo que quiero hacer es restarlos. Al hacer la suma si me da un resultado esperado: 55. Y al hacerle la resta me sale 5, en ves de -35.  Y el código es el que puse en la pregunta.

Comment: poque deberia darte -35, cuando tu codigo no hace eso?como llegas a -35? seguiste tu codigo?

Comment: @gbianchi para llegar -35, lo que tiene que hacer es: 10-9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1=-35

Ivan, lo que estas haciendo vos es:
1
2-1=1
3-1=2
4-2=2
5-2=3
6-3=3
7-3=4
8-4=4
9-4=5
10-5=5
resultado=5

Te recomiendo revisar la logica.

Comment: por eso se lo pregunte @FrancoBerardi... esta usando el algoritmo para invertir el array, para hacer la resta...

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Con esa lógica las operaciones no se están haciendo en el orden deseado. Para este problema recomiendo fijar un valor parcial en cada recursión, guardandolo en el propio vector. Algo así:

```
public class Gestor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int resultado;
        int[]vector = {1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        resultado = RestaVector(vector, vector.length);
        System.out.println("La resta del valor es: "+resultado);
    } 
        
    public static int RestaVector(int[] vector, int tam) {
        if(tam==2)
            return vector[1]-vector[0];
        else {
            vector[tam-2]=vector[tam-1]-vector[tam-2];
            return RestaVector(vector, tam - 1);
        }
    }  
}
```